# how many arrays exist with specific elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many $m \times n$ arrays exist with elements $0,1 \text{ or } 3$?

I thought that there are $(m \cdot n)^3$ arrays,but I am not sure..Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Try $3^{mn}$ instead

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why?? Could you explain it further to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $mn$ elements and each one has $3$ possibilities for its value. By the multiplicative property of outcomes for joint events, you thus have $3^{mn}$ possibilities for your matrix. (i.e. a product of $mn$ values of $3$)

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!